# can't exclude directories on backuppc

Tags: backuppc

i am tring to configure BackupPc to EXCLUDE some directories on my backups.

I need to exclude many (very big) caches directories from backups on
different machines

can you help me?

this is my configuration but doen't work, navigationg on the backups i
always have /wp-content/cache/ directory filled of GB of files

```
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = {
  '*' => [
    '/*/wp-content/cache/',
    '/wp-content/cache/*',
    './wp-content/cache/',
    'wp-content/cache/',
    'wp-content/cache/*'
  ]
};
```

i tried many values on $Conf{BackupFilesExclude} without success

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an example configuration I used:

```
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = {
 '/var' => [ '.Trash*', '/cache', '/lock', '/spool/exim4', '/run', '/tmp' ],
 '*' => [ '.cache', '.gvfs', '.thumbnails', '.Trash*', 'Cache', 'Dropbox' ]
};
```

This ignores all the `/cache` directories under `/var`.  Directories named `.cache` or `Cache` are also ignored.  I am not sure you can use wildcards when listing directories.

If you have multiple WordPress caches under `/opt` you may want to try `/opt/* => [ '/wp-content/cache' ]`. Adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the 'tar' method, all you need is something like this:

```
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = {
    '*' => [
        'wp-content/cache'
    ]
};
```

You should [not include a trailing slash, or tar will ignore it](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#_conf_backupfilesexclude_). And you only want to include the preceding slash if it is directly at the root of the "share" or folder being backed up.

If the 'wp-content/cache' folder is at the root of the share, it could also look like so:

```
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = {
    '*' => [
        '/wp-content/cache'
    ]
};
```

Wildcards are only needed for matching partial folder/file names.